# Reverse sort list by max element

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors

```
l = list(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(2,3),c(7,8),c(5,6))
```

and would to reverse sort it by the vector maximums:

```
> l
[[1]]
[1] 7 8

[[2]]
[1] 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 2 3

[[5]]
[1] 1 2
```

Any idea how I could do this in a one liner? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is

```
l[order(sapply(l, max), decreasing=TRUE)]
#[[1]]
#[1] 7 8

#[[2]]
#[1] 5 6

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 4

#[[4]]
#[1] 2 3

#[[5]]
#[1] 1 2
```

You could replace `sapply(l, max)` with `vapply(l, max, numeric(1L))` as well.

Or a compact form suggested by @DavidArenburg

```
l[order(-sapply(l, max))]
```

Comment: Nice answer, I think you can shorten it to just `l[order(-sapply(l, max))]`